# Build error using C++ Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, makefile, mingw

I configured my Eclipse Helios for C++ using MinGW and MSYS. I added the same to the PATH variable. However I am not able to Build using Eclipse. The error message below itself has little information :

```
Build of configuration Debug for project Test
Internal Builder is used for build               
g++ -IC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\Test.o ..\src\Test.cpp
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 220  ms.
```

I am able to use make/g++ from command line.

thanks

More Logs once I enabled "Don't fail on error" setting :

```
**** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project Test ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -IC:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\Test.o ..\src\Test.cpp
g++ -oTest.exe src\Test.o
g++: error: src\Test.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Build completed with errors
Time consumed: 337  ms.
```

Comment: Just to make sure, how did you "added the same to the PATH variable"?

Usually I set the **user environment variable** as **mingw\bin**.

Comment: I don't see what is the _actual_ error - is it something like g++ not found or some other error?

Comment: That is the maximum error trace I can see. How can I enable more logging to get the error trace.

Comment: I added the following to the PATH variabe C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;

Comment: Posting here because I had similar error but very hard to find the casue. I had `"some\windows\path\"` in Eclipse settings. The last, unnecessary backslash in the path made the linker/compiler command with an escaped `"` which have made entire rest of the command an uncompleted string. Damn MS, I hate their backslash paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the '-o' and the filenames in your 2 g++ command-lines.